# How to dynamically change the color of a column in the angular material table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a table generated with `ngFor` and I need to change the color of all the data in the `Status` column to green. I do not understand in what place exactly and how I need to apply.

```html
<section class="transaction">
  <div class="transaction__inner">
    <ul class="transaction__select-transaction">
      <li *ngFor="let transactionType of transactionTypes" class="transaction__select-transaction-item">
        {{ transactionType }}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="transaction__form-table-wrapper">
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns" [matColumnDef]="column.columnDef">
          <th class="transaction__table-header" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
            {{ column.header }}
          </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            {{ column.cell(row) }}
          </td>
        </ng-container>
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Could you please only show the relevant `<table>` html, and create example `dataSource` and `columns` variables so the problem is easily reproducible?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply change the styling of the tags within the `matColumnDef` container. Here is a simple example using the `[ngClass]` directive.

**CSS**

```css
table {
  width: 50%;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

**Typescript**

```js
  dataSource = [
    { col1: 1, col2: 2, col3: 3 },
    { col1: 4, col2: 5, col3: 6 },
    { col1: 7, col2: 8, col3: 9 },
  ];
  columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'];

  getClass(column: string) {
    if (column === 'col2') return 'green';
    return '';
  }
```

**HTML**

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns" [matColumnDef]="column">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [ngClass]="getClass(column)">
      {{ column }}
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [ngClass]="getClass(column)">
      {{ element[column] }}
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columns"></tr>
</table>
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vfjcjk?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: how can I apply your code to mine, I have differences and therefore fail ?

Comment: You would need to supply me with a reproducible example for me to show you. Please see the comment I left on your question.